# what is the meaning of "===" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have seen many uses of "===" in conditional statements.

Can anyone tell me what does it mean?

something like ternary operator?

```
if(typeof(x) == "string")
{
    x= (x=== "true");
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: `===` is *strict* equality comparison.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Means that both the value and implicit data type are the same.

Comment: @mbratch Obligatory retort: http://w3fools.com :)

Comment: === used to test value + type

Comment: @deceze doesn't really matter for such a basic question

Comment: @deceze, cute but the OP could easily find the answer at the link I provided or simple Google search. So will this be another case of a question easily sought out in programming documentation that tallies hundreds of upvotes for answers? Good grief...

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1121982

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: I'm not saying W3S is particularly wrong in this case, just that one should not regard it as a primary source of knowledge! Many newbs don't know that.

Comment: lmgtfy: http://bit.ly/16CJ6ug

Comment: Read This Tutorial http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/javascript-equality.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `===` operator checks for equality which means that the `type` and `value` are the same.  The `==` operator checks for equivalence which means that the `value` is the same and it disregards the type.

**Example**

```
alert("1" == 1); //alerts true
alert("1" === 1); //alerts false, types are different.
alert(1 === 1); //alerts true
```

This can be useful in Javascript due to the loosely typed nature of the language and the truthy/falsey nature of variables.

For example, an empty String is `==` false

```
("") ? alert(true): alert(false); //alerts false
```

You will also find that `0` is `==` false

```
(0) ? alert(true): alert(false); //alerts false
```

As well as an empty property on an object:

```
({}.prop) ? alert(true): alert(false); //alerts false
```

In these situations it may be necessary to use the `===` operator when type is important.

Answer (score 2):

It's `strict equality comparison`. It means that not just the value is evaluated but also the type of the objects. More info is available in the [ECMAScript-specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6).

Answer (score 0):

The `===` mean "equality without type coercion". Using the triple equals both the values *and their types* must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

"===" does not perform type conversion so it could have a different result than "==".

Comment: You mean type checking, instead of type conversion ?

Comment: No, I mean type conversion. `==` converts types so it can compare them, `===` does not do that and compare as is. Therefore `'' == false` is `true` whereas `'' === false` is `false`

Answer (score 0):

The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.